# APEX: Access to a sObject Field via String(dynamically)

Tags: apex

I have an object instance of a sObject, for example Product.

```
Product2 x = new Product2();
```

Now I can access the field of object like that

```
x.Name = 'Bruce Wayne';
```

My questions is about this

```
.Name
```

part.

Is there any workaround to access field of our sObject with a String?
What I mean

```
String s ='Name';
x.s = 'Bruce Wayne';
```

I have a certain Field API's in Custom Metadata and I need access only fields from this Metadata. I can retrieve them via SOQL, but what then? I have strings and can't do anything more.
I have already tried converting String to schemaField sObject, but it does not work since after a dot operator (x.) the Apex automatically treat everything as a hardcoded field API value.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `SObject.put` method to write to a field using its name:

```
Product2 record = new Product2();
record.put('Name', 'some value');
```

Similarly, if you would like to retrieve a value from a field, you can use `SObject.get`:

```
Object value = record.get('Name');
// OR
String name = (String)record.get('Name');
```

Comment: You'll have to cast the field though, so the correct syntax is (String)record.get('Name') or record.get('Name') != null ? (String)record.get('Name') : null;  (More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get)

Comment: @JamesLoghry Please do not advocate `record.get('Name') != null? (String)record.get('Name'): null;` ... `(String)record.get('Name')` is always sufficient, and this design can cause significant performance problems in highly dynamic code.

Comment: There's a potential that Name can be null (for instance if you don't query the field in SOQL, or you can upsert with a null name in rare occasions, but it would be prudent to check for null in custom or standard fields as well.  Although it might not be the most performant thing per se, it's better than throwing a null pointer exception when you cast from an Object to the proper field type. So yes, I'll continue "advocating" for null checks, because programming.

Comment: Casting a null does not throw NPE. You can quite easily verify with an anonymous script. `Object foo; String bar = (String)foo;`

Comment: Yep, you're right.  Still would need to check for nulls in other cases such as calling methods on the fields like Name, but you're right on the casting piece. My bad

Comment: I'm not the one who called you out. :) But still, better to cache the value if you need to reference it twice for any reason. Dynamic `.get` calls have been expensive in the past when I profiled them.